# How to realize persistence of a complex graph with an Object Database?

Tags: graph, tree, db4o, object-oriented-database, data-persistence

I have several graphs. The breadth and depth of each graph can vary and will undergo changes and alterations during runtime. See example graph.

[image]

There is a root node to get a hold on the whole graph (i.e. tree). A node can have several children and each child serves a special purpose. Furthermore a node can access all its direct children in order to retrieve certain informations. On the other hand a child node may not be aware of its own parent node, nor other siblings. Nothing spectacular so far.

Storing each graph and updating it with an object database (in this case DB4O) looks pretty straightforward. I could have used a relational database to accomplish data persistence (including database triggers, etc.) but I wanted to realize it with an object database instead.

There is one peculiar thing with my graphs. See another example graph.

[image]

To properly perform calculations some nodes require informations from other nodes. These other nodes may be siblings, children/grandchildren or related in some other kind. In this case a specific node knows the other relevant nodes as well (and thus can get the required informations directly from them). For the sake of simplicity the first image didn't show all potential connections.

If one node has a change of state (e.g. triggered by an internal timer or triggered by some other node) it will inform other nodes (interested obsevers, see also [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)) about the change. Each informed node will then take appropriate actions to update its own state (and in turn inform other observers as needed). A root node will not know about every change that occurs, since only the involved nodes will know that something has changed. If such a chain of events is triggered by the root node then of course it's not much of an issue.

The aim is to assure data persistence with an object database. Data in memory should be in sync with data stored within the database. What adds to the complexity is the fact that the graphs don't consist of simple (and stupid) data nodes, but that lots of functionality is integrated in each node (i.e. events that trigger state changes throughout a graph).

I have several rough ideas on how to cope with the presented issue (e.g. (1) stronger separation of data and functionality or (2) stronger integration of the database or (3) set an arbitrary time interval to update data and accept that data may be out of synch for a period of time). I'm looking for some more input and options concerning such a key issue (which will definitely leave significant footprints on a concrete implementation).

*(edited)
There is another aspect I forgot to mention. A graph should not reside all the time in memory. Graphs that are not needed will be only present in the database and thus put in a state of suspension. This is another issue which needs consideration. While in suspension the update mechanisms will probably be put to sleep as well and this is not intended.*

Answer (score 1):

In the case of db4o check out "transparent activation" to automatically load objects on demand as you traverse the graph (this way the graph doesn't have to be all in memory) and check out "transparent persistence" to allow each node to persist itself after a state change.

http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2009/12/db4o-transparent-persistence/

Moreover you can use db4o "callbacks" to trigger custom behavior during db4o operations.

HTH

German

Answer (score 1):

What's the exact question? Here a few comments:

As @German already mentioned: For complex object graphs you probably want to use [transparent persistence](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/transparent_persistence.htm).

Also as @German mentione: [Callback](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/callbacks/event_registry_api.htm) can help you to do additional stuff when objects are read/written etc on the database.

To the Observer-Pattern. Are you on .NET or Java? Usually you don't want to store the observers in the database, since the observers are usually some parts of your business-logic, GUI etc. On .NET events are automatically not stored. On Java make sure that you mark the field holding the observer-references as transient.

In case you actually want to store observers, for example because they are just other elements in your object-graph. On .NET, you cannot store delegates / closures. So you need to introduce a interface for calling the observer. On Java: Often we use anonymous inner classes as listener: While db4o can store those, I would NOT recommend that. Because a anonymous inner class gets generated name which can change. Then db4o will not find that class later if you've changed your code.

Thats it. Ask more detailed questions if you want to know more.